# How to keycloak js updateToken despite its valid in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keycloak

I have VueJS frontend connected to Keycloak via keycloack-js openid. No implicit flow

[image]

There is a situation where Backend NodeJS add Groups to a user in Keycloak. In order to get those groups out of JWT user need to logout and login in Frontend.

I tried to  **keycloak.updateToken()** but as long access token is valid the function is not updating my token. Any Chance to force keycloack js to update token regardless its valid?

Answer (score 0):

to force it requires an input **-1**

```
keycloak.updateToken(-1)
```